# Simple PHP OOP -> Insert to database

Tags: php, sql

i am having some problem with my code, i try to simple insert some logs when user use search on my site.

Log should contains:

```
date in unix time -> using function for it
username -> its stored in Session
vin -> its string he post in input field
```

Top of the class

```
public $vin = null;
public function __construct( $data = array() )
{
    if( isset( $data['vin'] ) )
        $this->vin = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['vin'] ) );
}

public function storeFormValues( $params )
{
    $this->__construct( $params ); 
}
```

function code:

```
 public function logFromSearch() {
    $correct = false;
    //$this->username = $_SESSION]['username'];
    $date = new DateTime();

    try {
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "INSERT INTO logs(date, user, vin) VALUES(:date, :user, :vin)";

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "date", $date->getTimestamp(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "user", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        echo $this->vin;
        echo $date->getTimestamp();
        $stmt->execute();
        return "Everything is OKEY";
    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
 }
```

Its not importing anything to database dispite the fact it should in my opinion. I try to debug it so i found out my way of adding username from session is not possible way and also find out that `this->vin` and `$date->getTimestamp()` is returning actual data which it should insert to database so can somebody help me to find where is the problem? (in same class i am using other function for database connection and they work find so its not in setting up connecting  / db name and host and so on because its in different file)

P.S. Errors : I dont get any errors just single notice Notice: Undefined property: Data::$username which is understandable.

Comment: Whats inside DB_HOST, DB_USEr and DB_PASS ?

Comment: confirm that `$username` actually contains some data. `var_dump($this->username)`

Comment: @Xatenev 
    `define( "DB_HOST", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8" );    
    define( "DB_USER", "root" );
    define( "DB_PASS", "" );` I am using same things for more DB connection on same DB but different table so it should work

@iroegbu username is not defined there but it should still insert blanked DB column. I try it without username so just insert vin and date and still nothing happend

Comment: I expect this gonna be easy and i have just small mystake there but looks its not that easy :)